# Vuforia VUMark working in Editor but not on device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

We've recently implemented Vuforia using Vumarkers and are about to purchase a license. We've tested with the 'tuxedo' test Vumarker from Vuforia. Both in the Editor and Android worked just fine.

As a final step in our development process, we've made our own Vumarker using the Illustrator template. Everything works fine, the marker was validated, uploaded to their website and we've generated some test markers. Everything works fine in the Unity Editor.

But when we build our project on any device no markers are detected at all and no errors are thrown. Does anyone else experience this problem? We've tested in all light environments and marker sizes to make sure it's not a camera problem.

We've used the following versions

- Unity 2017.3.0f3 Windows 64bit
- Vuforia 7.0.36
- Android 7.x

Answer (score 0):

If you have indeed successfully created vumark instances and downloaded the dataset, and you are sure nothing is detected and no errors are thrown, and if you are using the exact code from the sample and only replaced the dataset...

Then the first option that comes to mind is - did you load and activate the new dataset associated with the VuMarks?

Comment: Yup, we did load the dataset. Everything is working fine in the editor too. It is just the Android build that is not working.